# Passport.js Strategy for Synology SSO

Tags: node.js, passport.js, synology

I‘ve seen, that Synology provides a Single-Sign-On package for their Diskstations that provides an OAuth Interface for authentication. (See https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Synology_SSO_API_Guide.pdf)

I would like to implement this in my node.js application, which is running on the diskstation to authenticate the users.

Do someone have an idea, how I could implement a passport.js strategy for this or is there another solution for node.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A solution without passport would be to manually create the session after validating the authentication data in api of the synology, the passport only streamlines this process nothing that can not be done without it. [Example](https://github.com/andersonmendesdev/exampleLogin). [Api Doc synology](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/DeveloperGuide/Synology_Download_Station_Web_API.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I've implemented some node.js+react code that integrates with Synology's SSO Server.

You can see my implementation [here](https://github.com/uriagassi/paperless.node/blob/main/server/auth/SynologySSO.ts) - you are welcome to integrate it into your code.

In a nutshell - the client API is:

https://my_dsm:5001/webman/sso/SSOOauth.cgi?scope=user_id&redirect_uri=--redirect_uri-here--&synossoJSSDK=false&app_id=--appid_here--

and the token exchange API (on the server side), given the client token is:

https://my_dsm:5001/webman/sso/SSOAccessToken.cgi?action=exchange&app_id=--appid_here--&access_token=--token_here--

There is also a logout API, though it doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The described SSO isn't really OAuth compliant, however, for Alexa integration they needed that. It's a bit trimmed down, but works once you've registered your app.

If you'd like to utilize the built in OAuth Server (you'll have to register your application via SSH), I've got some manual for you: https://medium.com/@4c.dmnk/take-control-over-synologys-oauth-service-f96114be3707

short:

- you’ll need SSH: access enable the service, connect, get root access
  with `sudo -i`
- cd to the packages location
  */usr/local/packages/@appstore/OAuthService/tools*
- register your app, and take the secret

[image: oauth app registration]

- authenticate against *https://yourDSM.domain.demo:5001/oauth/oauth_login.cgi*